# Receiving Invalid Address on Web3

Tags: solidity, web3js, metamask, javascript

I am having issues launching my web3 connected to Solidity (on Remix) and MetaMask. The error that popped out was that I have an invalid address and they were referencing the function called getSellerCount.
Here is my Solidity:

```
pragma solidity 0.8.15; 
contract ShippingContract{
    uint public sellerCount;
}
```

Here is My HTML code:

```
<div id="sellerlist">
        <h1>Seller List</h1>
        <hr/><br/>
        <table class="table"> <!--display the list of seller registrations-->
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">seller Number</th>
                    <th scope="col">Seller Name</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="sellerListResults">
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <br/>
        <span id="sellermessage"></span> <hr/> <!--display message-->
    </div>
```

Here is my javascript codes:

```
    function ShippingContractApp(Contract) {
    this.web3 = null;
    this.instance = null;
    this.Contract = Contract;
}
ShippingContractApp.prototype.onReady = function() {
    this.init(function () {
        $('#sellermessage').append("DApp loaded successfully.");
        
    });
    this.bindButtons(); //bind the button to their respective functions
    this.loadShippingRegistration();
}

ShippingContractApp.prototype.init = function(cb) {
        // enable and connect to MetaMask
        if (window.ethereum) {
            this.web3 = new Web3(ethereum);
        try {
            ethereum.enable();
        } catch (error) {
        }
         }  
    
        // Create the contract interface using the ABI provided in the configuration.
        var contract_interface = this.web3.eth.contract(this.Contract.abi);
    
        // Create the contract instance for the specific address provided in the configuration.
        this.instance = contract_interface.at(this.Contract.address);
    
        cb();
    }

if(typeof(Contracts) === "undefined") var Contracts={ ShippingContract: { abi: [] }};
var shippingContractApp = new ShippingContractApp(Contracts['ShippingContract']);

$(document).ready(function() {
    shippingContractApp.onReady();
});
ShippingContractApp.prototype.getSellerCount = function (cb) {
this.instance.sellerCount(function (error, sellerCount) {
    cb(error, sellerCount);
});
};
ShippingContractApp.prototype.loadShippingRegistration = function () {
var that = this;
this.getSellerCount(function (error, sellerCount) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
    $("#sellermessage").text("Seller Count: " + sellerCount);
    $("#sellerListResults").empty(); //empty the house registration list table
}
```

and here is my abi(javascript) :

```
var Contracts = { ShippingContract:  {
    abi:[
{
    "inputs": [],
    "name": "sellerCount",
    "outputs": [
        {
            "internalType": "uint256",
            "name": "",
            "type": "uint256"
        }
    ],
    "stateMutability": "view",
    "type": "function"
}
],

    address: "0x1abE4A15B9f04e2b3F0668AD66543f2673368B29",
    endpoint: "https://sepolia.infura.io/v3/undefined"
   }}
```

Comment: did you check that the contract with the address 0x1abe.... exists on the network you have selected to work with?

Comment: yup! I just redeployed and swap the old address and abi with the new one but it still gives me the same error.

Comment: really? well I queried 0x1abE4A15B9f04e2b3F0668AD66543f2673368B29 address on Ropsten and it doesn't exist there

Comment: ah wait, I see what might have went wrong. I was using Sepolia for my metaMask instead... Though I am still encountering the same issue after the change

Comment: if you send a eth_getCode() API request to your network, does it return any bytecode or is it empty?

Comment: I think I solved it, for some odd reason when I switched my solidity version to ^0.5.10, I do not have the error anymore